# How to connect exisitng project with Redis Cloud?

Tags: python, database, networking, redis, dns

I wanted to connect the Redis Cloud Database with my Python project. However I am getting error

```
2/23/2024, 11:40:04 AM | ERROR | DatabaseService | Failed to add database. | {"stack":\[{"message":"getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN redis-18108.c299.asia-northeast1-1.gce.cloud.redislabs.com"}\]}
```

I am Windows user, I am running Redis through Docker and it is fine, locally I can store data, but cannot connect to cloud. Anyone could help me with that problem?

I checked my DNS and it is fine. Used nslookup and DNS query was successfully resolved. But still it is not connecting. Tried through redis_cli, got error:

```
Error 11002 connecting to redis-18108.c299.asia-northeast1-1.gce.cloud.redislabs.com:18108. getaddrinfo failed.
```

Also tried to use command:

```
redis-cli -u redis://default:\*\*\*\*\*\*\*@redis-18108.c299.asia-northeast1-1.gce.cloud.redislabs.com:18018
```

Comment: I used redis lab long ago for some experiments. I think you will have to add your ip to its whitelist to allow access to redis from your system.

Comment: @S_s Thank you, stranger, that was the problem that took 7 hours of my life((((.

Comment: Glad its resolved.